# Checking validity of permutations in python

Tags: python, permutation

Using python, I would like to generate all possible permutations of 10 labels (for simplicity, I'll call them `a`, `b`, `c`, ...), and return all permutations that satisfy a list of conditions. These conditions have to do with the ordering of the different labels - for example, let's say I want to return all permutations in which `a` comes before `b` and when `d` comes after `e`. Notably, none of the conditions pertain to any details of the labels themselves, only their relative orderings. I would like to know what the most suitable data structure and general approach is for dealing with these sorts of problems. For example, I can generate all possible permutations of elements within a list, but I can't see a simple way to verify whether a given permutation satisfies the conditions I want.

Comment: Without a more detailed explanation of your conditions, it seems difficult to give you any advice. Maybe you could start by clarifying your conditions, then see if it is easier to generate the valid combinations directly, or to generate all and reject the invalid ones. I'm afraid that your question is too broad as it stands now...

Comment: Sorry, is the example I gave not sufficient? All the conditions that I care about are of the form "`a` comes before `b`" strung together with "or" and "and" operations (the exact problem at hand involves about 20 of these conditions though, in a way that makes me suspect that it's too hard to obtain the valid permutations constructively).

Comment: Then you should probably build all permutations and reject. If your problem is how to check the validity of a permutation, maybe you should give a simplified example of what you want to achieve, with some example of rule, and where you get stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"The most suitable data structure and general approach" varies, depending on the actual problem. I can outline three basic approaches to the problem you give (generate all permutations of 10 labels `a`, `b`, `c`, etc. in which `a` comes before `b` and `d` comes after `e`).

**First,** generate all permutations of the labels, using `itertools.permutations`, remove/skip over the ones where `a` comes after `b` and `d` comes before `e`. Given a particular permutation `p` (represented as a Python tuple) you can check for

```
p.index("a") < p.index("b") and p.index("d") > p.index("e")
```

This has the disadvantage that you reject three-fourths of the permutations that are initially generated, and that expression involves four passes through the tuple. But this is simple and short and most of the work is done in the fast code inside Python.

**Second**, general all permutation of the *locations* `0` through `9`. Consider these to represent the *inverses* of your desired permutations. In other words, the number at position `0` is not what will go to position `0` in the permutation but rather shows where label `a` will go in the permutation. Then you can quickly and easily check for your requirements:

```
p[0] < p[1] and p[3] > p[4]
```

since `a` is the 0'th label, etc. If the permutation passes this test, then find the inverse permutation of this and apply it to your labels. Finding the inverse involves one or two passes through the tuple, so it makes fewer passes than the first method. However, this is more complicated and does more work outside the innards of Python, so it is very doubtful that this will be faster than the first method.

**Third,** generate only the permutations you need. This can be done with these steps.

3a. Note that there are four special positions in the permutations (those for `a`, `b`, `d`, and `e`). So use `itertools.combinations` to choose 4 positions out of the 10 total positions. Note I said positions, not labels, so choose 4 integers between `0` and `9`.

3b. Use `itertools.combinations` again to choose 2 of those positions out of the 4 already chosen in step 3a. Place `a` in the first (smaller) of those 2 positions and `b` in the other. Place `e` in the first of the other 2 positions chosen in step 3a and place `d` in the other.

3c. Use `itertools.permutations` to choose the order of the other 6 labels.

3d. Interleave all that into one permutation. There are several ways to do that. You could make one pass through, placing everything as needed, or you could use slices to concatenate the various segments of the final permutation.

That third method generates only what you need, but the time involved in constructing each permutation is sizable. I do not know which of the methods would be fastest--you could test with smaller sizes of permutations. There are multiple possible variations for each of the methods, of course.